# SQL split totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Currently I have the following result in SQL:

| qty | description | volume | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Flowers | 3,4 | 4 |

This is in an XML format. So what I want to do, and I think I need to user "FOR XML PATH" in a certain way, but I am not sure how to achieve the following result:

| qty | description | volume | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Flowers | 0,85 | 1 |
| 1 | Flowers | 0,85 | 1 |
| 1 | Flowers | 0,85 | 1 |
| 1 | Flowers | 0,85 | 1 |

So I need to divide the XML path based on the total qty (4). For each (4) products, I need to create a new row. Then divide the volume and the weight (/qty).

Can anyone help me to push me into the right direction?

Edit:
The first result, qty of 4, is a result in a temp table.
I extract the data from the temp table into XML format. Here is a snippet

```
(SELECT "qty" = value('(@col24)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),  "weight"  = value('(@col28)[1]', 'varchar(50)'), "volume" = value('(@col26)[1]', 'decimal(16,2)') FOR XML PATH('product'), ROOT('products'), TYPE)
```

The qty, weight and volume represents the totals.
This is what I want to devide to create a "product" for each "qty".

Comment: are you using microsoft sql server database?

Comment: share your current sql also..

Comment: I am using SQL server indeed

Comment: You contradict yourself by saying you have the result in SQL, but it's an XML format. Which is it? What does your actual input look like? For that matter, what does your output look like -- should it be rows or XML?

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] your question to include more details; comments are a bad medium for this as they're neither persistent nor particularly readable when lots of code is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to split the rows (you might need to up the recursion limit if your quantity can be higher than 100).

```
declare @Test table (qty int, [description] varchar(64), volume decimal(9,2), [weight] decimal(9,2))

insert into @Test (qty, [description], volume, [weight]) values (4, 'Flowers', 3.4, 4);

with cte as (
  select qty, [description], volume, [weight], 1 as rn
  from @Test
  union all
  select qty, [description], volume, [weight], rn + 1
  from cte
  where rn < qty
)
select 1 qty, [description], cast(volume / qty as decimal(9,2)) volume, cast([weight] / qty as decimal(9,2)) [weight]
from cte
for xml path('product'), root('products'), type;
-- option (maxrecursion 200); -- If you need to increase it above the default of 100
```

Note: If you setup the DDL+DML, as I shown, in your questions you make it much easier for people to reply.

Answer (score 0):

One way is by recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, qty AS cc, 1 org FROM #sale 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT cte.qty /qty
         , cte.description
         , cte.volume /qty
         , cte.weight /qty
         , cte.cc - 1 AS cc 
         ,  0 org
    FROM cte
    WHERE cc > 1
    )

SELECT * FROM cte
where org = 0 
FOR XML path
```

However if you have a tally table it will faster and simpler:

```
SELECT qty /qty
     , description
     , volume /qty
     , weight /qty
FROM table
JOIN numbertables < -- number tables from 1 to max
  on  numbertables.values < qty
FOR XML path
```